# Why im getting provider error in project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

Im getting this error when im trying to use provider in my code .
IN new in flutter and a beginner so maybe anyone can explain how to fix I search already but still cannot find something.

```
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building MeinAccount(dirty, state: _MeinAccountState#e2cbb):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this MeinAccount Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that MeinAccount is under your MultiProvider/Provider<User>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  

  consider using `builder` like so:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MeinAccount file:///Users/myname/StudioProjects/projectname/lib/main.dart:48:41
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:332:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:284:30)
#2      _MeinAccountState.build (package:projectname/seitenleiste/meinacount.dart:362:27)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4704:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4587:15)
```

This is my widget UPDATEEE:

```
Widget _buildPasswordTF() {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatbaseService(uid:user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Password',
```

Maybe anyone can help :

Also here's my main dart UPDATEEE:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return MultiProvider(
       providers: [
         //DatbaseService(create: (_) => User()), // add your providers like this.
       ],
       child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title:'Appbar Scaffold',
            theme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              primaryColor: Colors.white,
```

If you need more informations please add a comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you haven't registered your provider. You need to register them, before consuming them. Wrap your MaterialApp widget with MultiProvider (if you have multiple providers in your app).

example:

```
 child: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => User()), // add your providers like this.
            ],
      child:MaterialApp(..........)
);
```